# Altium .Designator on Mechanical Layer

Tags: altium

Is there a way to have the .Designator string in the component footprint center on the component? Designator string R1 will look left-justified on the component (which it is), and string R11 will **seem** centered simply because it's 3 characters long. It would just look a lot neater if it was center justified.

Comment: Sadly I don't think so. I justify it usually such that components that will probably have 3 digits (resistors, caps, etc) will fit nicely in the outline.

Comment: @KrunalDesai That is good information, but it is more fit to be an answer to the question, and not a comment! Feel free to post an answer if you know the solution.

Comment: I normally would have, but was on mobile and didn't feel like I had enough content at the time for an answer -- no worries though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I deal with it.

I agree with Krunal in the comments, generally it is not possible.

Every component I make has a .Designator string on a mechanical layer. I size it so that it can fit 3-4 digits within the outline.

Once the design is going into production, I go to the mechanical layer and rotate and re-adjust all the component strings as necessary to create an assembly drawing. I just end up with better results that way, putting a little manual labor into it!